# Weblogic 12c HTTP Request call executed severals times by thread pools?

Tags: weblogic

Using Weblogic 12c, i have a big problem: when calling a rest service using differents clients (java client or using command line like curl) there is no problem.
BUT when the client is in C#, the request is executed severals time (each minutes) by one different thread of the pool so it implies lot of errors in log files because:

The C# client get its response and close the connection, but the others 'duplicated' requests (by threads pools) creates stacks errors because the service can not write a response (there is no client to get the response).

Some precisions:
- There is no Stuck thread in my case.
- Using Tomcat there is no problem
- There is the same problem using new installed Weblogic12c Server (so there is no custom configuration)
- The http headers are the same between C# or others clients
- The same data tests are used to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

check access.log to check how many requests are received by the server, if its more in case of c# then its a problem there not the server.

You can also enable http debug to get more details about the incoming request.